# Weird padding issue with Chrome (but not Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

The issue is visible at the frontpage. Chrome adds a little padding to the lower part of `#main-container` and I can not seem to find where and why it is added. It is a custom page template and so are many others but the others seem to be fine.
The footer box has a top-margin of 20px and that is intentional - that should be the only margin between the frontpage main content and the footer.

I have added a gray background to the #main-container in the front-page to make it stant out more.

I have toyed around with the site for a bit now and could not find the right solution. I have a made a little demonstration picture that shows the issue. You can see the picture here: http://www.upload.ee/image/2380775/paddingissue.jpg

Can anyone point me to the right direction as to why its happening and how to fix it?

```
You can see the site live at:
www.uber.fi
U: xxx
PW: xxx
```

Comment: I see you've changed the passwords in the original post. Please note that they are still visible in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10784251/revisions), so if you don't want people to access your site anymore you'll have to change the password for your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the whitespace at the end of the `#primary-container`. That is causing the issues.

[image]

Comment: I was just preparing an answer. The problem is that this whitespace actually contains an unicode BOM sequence, which apparently causes Chrome to not collapse it.

Comment: I changed the relevant files encodings to UTF-8 without BOM and it seems to be fixed! I wouldv'e never discovered it myself so my sincere thanks!

Comment: Funny, I just ran into a similar issue a few days ago. Apparently, the only place where you'll ever want to use a BOM is the main document you're including from, not any `include`d files. For me, the problem was that I included 3 files before the doctype which were all encoded as UTF-8 with a BOM, putting the browser into quirks mode. Removing the BOM from those included files fixed it. Good thing there are HEX editors. :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) can help you?